# SMS : Columns "_id" does not Exist

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

Trying to Delete just One(the Last) Message in SMS Using this Code :

```
 Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/");
    Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String pid0 = cur.getString(1);

 /*Force Close Here, illegal State for the Cursor, Couldn't Read Row 0, Col -1, From CursorWindows : 

 String pid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("_id"));*/


        String where = "thread_id=" + pid;
        String[] Columns= cur.getColumnNames();
        // do some process
        Log.e("TAG", "content://sms/conversations/" + pid0 + "/" + pid);


        mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + pid0 + "/" + pid), null, null);
```

The Method getColumnNames() Return Only 3 Columns : "thread_id", "msg_count", "snippet", i am looking for "_id" wich is Assigned to each Message, i get a Force Close when trying to read "_id", What's wrong ?

Edit : i am able now to Get the Message id, but unable to Delete the Message, Nothing Happen :

```
String id0 = cur.getString(0);
mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id0), null, null);
```

What's Wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the Problem was i was Querying "content://sms/conversations/" instead of "content://sms/",

Code :

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor cur = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
    ////Changed to 0 to get Message id instead of Thread id : 
    String MsgId= cur.getString(0);



    mContext.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + MsgId), null, null);
```

Thanks